# MYSQL Variables LIMIT and subquery

Tags: mysql, variables, subquery

I have a question about this mysql query on mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35:

I have a table named **mytable** with 3 columns `date`,`value` and `id_patient`.

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` 
( `date` DATE NOT NULL 
, `id_patient` INT(11) NOT NULL 
, `value` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO `mytable` (`date`, `id_patient`, `value`) VALUES 
('2019-11-17', '87321', '6'), 
('2019-11-18', '87321', '1'), 
('2019-11-19', '87321', '2'), 
('2019-11-20', '87321', NULL), 
('2019-11-21', '87321', '5'), 
('2019-11-22', '87321', '8'), 
('2019-11-23', '87321', NULL), 
('2019-11-24', '87321', '3'), 
('2019-11-25', '87321', '4'), 
('2019-11-26', '87321', '6'), 
('2019-11-27', '87321', '1'), 
('2019-11-28', '87321', '10');
```

For each row i need to know the sum of 4th previous values not null.

```
SELECT @date:=date, value, 

(     SELECT SUM(value)
      FROM mytable 
      WHERE date<@date 
      AND id_patient=87321 
      AND value IS NOT NULL 
      ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,4 ) somme  

FROM mytable 
WHERE id_patient=87321
```

It doesnt work. The result is the same with or without `ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,4` and every rows before the current rows are selected.

Somebody know why ?

There is an example of the expected result:

```
+-------------+--------------------+--------+
| @date:=date | value              | somme  |
+-------------+--------------------+--------+
| 2019-11-17  |                  6 |   NULL | SUM OF 0 previous values not null
| 2019-11-18  |                  1 |      6 | SUM OF 1 previous values not null
| 2019-11-19  |                  2 |      7 | SUM OF 2 previous values not null
| 2019-11-20  |               NULL |      9 | SUM OF 3 previous values not null
| 2019-11-21  |                  5 |      9 | SUM OF 4 previous values not null
| 2019-11-22  |                  8 |     14 | SUM OF 4 previous values not null
| 2019-11-23  |               NULL |     16 | SUM OF 4 previous values not null
| 2019-11-24  |                  3 |     16 | SUM OF 4 previous values not null
| 2019-11-25  |                  4 |     18 | SUM OF 4 previous values not null
| 2019-11-26  |                  6 |     20 | SUM OF 4 previous values not null
| 2019-11-27  |                  1 |     21 | SUM OF 4 previous values not null
| 2019-11-28  |                 10 |     14 | SUM OF 4 previous values not null
+-------------+--------------------+--------+
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). Also, I'm unfamiliar with the term 'wait result'

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited my post  and changed the term 'wait result'. Sorry for my bad english... I hope it's better.

Comment: Does it have to be last sequential days?  Only 4 days, or just most recent?  What is overall objective to summing only 4.  What if several day gaps between visits for a patient, what confirms 4 days?

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: I need to compare the value of the day with the sum of the values ​​of the previous 4 days with a non-zero value. 

**For example** : 

i compare the value of  2019-11-28 with the sum of values between 2019-11-27 and 2019-11-24 ( 4 days ) because each value is not null.

But for 2019-11-25 I take values between 2019-11-19 ( 6 days ) because i have 2 null values )


I hope my explanation is clear enough

Comment: My version is:  mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a self join and aggregation:

```
select m.date, m.id_patient, m.value,
  sum(mm.value) somme
from mytable m left join mytable mm
on mm.id_patient = m.id_patient and mm.value is not null and mm.date < m.date 
and (
  select count(*) from mytable
  where id_patient = m.id_patient and value is not null 
  and date >= mm.date and date < m.date 
) <= 4
where m.id_patient = '87321'
group by m.date, m.id_patient, m.value
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2FP1QiSBx58MkCpEaiYsVq/1).
Results:

```
| date       | id_patient | value | somme |
| ---------- | ---------- | ----- | ----- |
| 2019-11-17 | 87321      | 6     |       |
| 2019-11-18 | 87321      | 1     | 6     |
| 2019-11-19 | 87321      | 2     | 7     |
| 2019-11-20 | 87321      |       | 9     |
| 2019-11-21 | 87321      | 5     | 9     |
| 2019-11-22 | 87321      | 8     | 14    |
| 2019-11-23 | 87321      |       | 16    |
| 2019-11-24 | 87321      | 3     | 16    |
| 2019-11-25 | 87321      | 4     | 18    |
| 2019-11-26 | 87321      | 6     | 20    |
| 2019-11-27 | 87321      | 1     | 21    |
| 2019-11-28 | 87321      | 10    | 14    |
```

Comment: thank you very much for this solution. It's a great way to go!

Answer (score 0):

The `sum()` already took place on all rows before you `limit` the results. `Limit` first the result before applying the `sum()` function using another `subquery`.

```
SELECT @date:=date, value, 
    (SELECT sum(value) from 
        (SELECT value
          FROM mytable 
          WHERE date<@date 
          AND id_patient=87321 
          AND value IS NOT NULL 
          ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,4))
FROM mytable 
WHERE date<@date 
    AND id_patient=87321 
    AND value IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly i already tried this but it seems the date variable doesn't change in the subquery because i have the same result for each line...

Comment: @FranckBarlet, i think you are trying to display these 4 days with same sum() value, try updated answer

Comment: No, the result is not the wait result... 
It's return only 4 rows with the same sum...
This query will kill me :)

Comment: For information : I added the wait result example in my post.

Comment: I think the subrequest is executed first. So the @date variable does not have any value at this time ...